# Change outlook signature based on recipient address

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

Is it possible to catch every time a mail's recipient address is changed and if it includes domains like hotmail or gmail? I've been asked to create an addin that will monitor the outlook application and when the user types a new mail, in the event that the "To" field is changed i will check the address that it contains and change the signature of the user accordingly. For example if user is sending email to gmail.com, the signature will be changed automatically to "Signature1" but if user is sending mail to a specific domain, say , @xyz.com, the signature will be "Signature2".

Answer (score 0):

You can trap the MailItem.PropertyChange event to detect when the To or Recipients properties change and modify the signature accordingly.  However, there is no method or property in the Outlook Object Model to automate the usage of signatures.  You'd have to edit the MailItem.HTMLBody property to insert the relevant signature from the files in the AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures directory.

Comment: i actually solved the problem by creating an outlook addin which checked if blocked terms were in the mail body when user clicks send button. However i can't deploy the solution to another pc.

Comment: Is your deployment problem a separate question?

Comment: it was. I also solved it and i will post my answer here for this problem.

Comment: @Codette Would you mind posting your answer if you still have it?